# Using gdb with inlined functions

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm trying to use `gdb` in postmortem mode with the core dump of a crashed process.  I can get a stack trace, but instead of showing me the actual location in the offending function, `gdb` shows me the line number of a two-line inlined function that the offending function calls.

The inlined function is called many, many places; how do I find which call triggered the crash?  How do I find the code immediately around the inlined function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the stack frame in question, print the instruction point (e.g. p $rip),
then use it to look it up manually with e.g. "addr2line -e  -i 0x84564756".

This doesn't scale, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the "many many calls to the inlined function" are all happening from within a single "offending function" (otherwise your question doesn't make sense to me).

Your best bet is to note the IP address of the crash point in `GDB`, then use `"objdump -dS ./a.out"` and find that IP in the output.

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting OPTIMIZE to NO (eg. setenv OPTIMIZE NO) and rebuild the project:  this tells compiler not optimize code, hence it may not inline function calls.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like to be able to do postmortems of optimized (release) builds so that we can analyze core dumps from customers.